# Add 100 SMS in iPhone programmatically

Tags: iphone, sms

I want to add 100 SMS in my iPhone programmatically. Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: Define "add" - do you want to create 100 drafts, send 100 messages or receive 100 messages?

Comment: Apple will hopefully never allow direct programmatica acces to the SMS api. You could spam some one with SMS messages. Not only that think about the bill you could run if an app keeps sending message after message. The solution a posted below is the only way to send an SMS message with the user clearly allow the send the message.

Comment: Voting to close as not a real question. This is six days old, and has not been improved in line with @ninetwozero's suggestion. Also OP: we like to see prior effort here, ideally with some code. Would you bear that in mind for next time? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`MFMessageComposeViewController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html) to present a viewController filled with text and numbers to the user. But you can't send automatically sms.

Comment: Actually, there is a file called sms.db in iPhone. This file is located at the following path /var/mobile/Library/SMS/sms.db. I want to add 100 SMS in this file programmatically. This is a SQLite file.

Answer (score 0):

You could use web based SMS API services I believe. Take a look at [Twilio](http://www.twilio.com/) as an example. Also the [One API Gateway](http://oneapi-gw.gsma.com/) is currently rolled out across Canada and will be expanding to other markets soon